# How to upload documents (PDFs) anonymously?

Tags: vpn, pdf, linux-mint, privacy, metadata

**Backgroud history**

I have a drive folder link, where I want to upload some PDFs anonymously. I am using the VPN of Opera. I want to share my solution for several lessons with my fellow students. Our professor gets a little snippish when we help each other, so if he by any chance should stumble upon the folder, I don't want anyone to know that it was **me** who uploaded the files.

At the end of the day it's not illegal what I am doing, but I don't want to hear some strong words from my professor for helping the others.

**How should I do it**

1. How shall I clean the PDFs?
2. Is it only the metadata I have to remove?
3. And how do I remove metadat for an entire folder full of files?
4. Is Opera VPN secure?

I am using Linux Mint.

**Please a step to step guid**

I am not a computer expert. So if you please could give me a step to step guide (like: download this by using this command in the terminal; remove the data of all files in the folder by using this comman etc.)

**Thank you so much <3**

Comment: Removing the metadata should be enough, but the simplest solution would be to just encrypt the file.  If you are still worried, then use a virtual machine to author the file, and don't use information that can identify you.  Of course, you have to understand, the server can still identify you, even if you remove the metadata.

Comment: @Ramhound thank you. But how do I remove metadata?

Comment: The PDF authoring tool of your choice should have that option, if not, there are web services that exist (which again you can use whichever one you want) that will also do it.  I will warn you again, that even if you remove the metadata, your professor can still identify who uploaded the documented.  I assume access to this drive link is somewhat restricted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't cheat. If you are just learning, nobody will be upset, but usually solutions to graded homework are shared and that is plagiarism.

Comment: It's not graded homework. And I don't "cheat", since it is me who upload my work to share it with the others. And our professor gets upset when we drink water in his lessons - he is really easy to upset. Helping each other by ungraded homework is something he gets angry over.